# How can I run extension DB updates?

Tags: extension, upgrade

When I update my civi extension simply by changing the codebase to the most recent version (because the most recent version is not showing up in the config options), my extension is broken.

I updated "nz.co.fuzion.omnipaymultiprocessor" from 1.7 to 2.2

Probably because some database changes required in the new version?

**I'm wondering if there is database update script like the drupal update.php equivalent?**

Answer (score 7):

The equivalent would be any of these:

- Navigate to `civicrm/admin/extensions/upgrade?reset=1`
- Navigate to "System Status" or "Manage Extensions". Those pages will link to the above.
- On CLI, run `cv ext:upgrade-db` (Download `cv` from https://github.com/civicrm/cv)

Comment: For Wordpress: https://example.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fadmin%2Fextensions%2Fupgrade&reset=1

Answer (score 1):

Try running https://{yoursite}/civicrm/clearcache and then go to Administer->System Status.  You should be prompted if there are extension db updates.
If that does not work try disable/re-enable the extension.

Comment: Could you specify the path for the system status please?

Comment: In the default menu, the link is actually in `Administer => Administration Console => System Status` (or you can find it in the footer). The link should be roughly `/civicrm/a/#/status` (with adjustments on on CMS). For cache-clearing, see also https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/tools/debugging/#clearing-the-cache

Answer (score 1):

drush cvupdb will run the database upgrade for civi

Comment: (well it does for us, but maybe we have some special sauce that i don't know about)